# minimum or no use of loops in scala for Rotated Hyper-Ellipsoid Function

Tags: scala

[Rotated Hyper-Ellipsoid Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ookwF.png)

i have implemented this function using two loops but i want to do it with out using loops for a list of integers

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(0) { (sum, pair) =>
    val (elem, index) = pair
    sum + elem * elem * (length - index)
  }
```

Comment: `{ case (sum, (elem, index)) => ...`

Comment: IMHO, `list.zipWithIndex.map { case (e, i) => e * e * (length-i) }.sum` looks even clearer

Comment: probably, but I don't think it is necessary to create an intermediate collection like you suggest.

Comment: @igorpcholkin using `.iterator` to avoid intermediate collections

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.